# IDE does not recognize file path on mac parallels

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, parallels

I am trying to create a project on Atmel Studio 6, which is similar to visual studio, but when I run the code, I get the errors:

No such file in directory.

No input file

I am using Atmed Studio on mac through a virtual machine using the software parallels. Which might be the issue.
The current file path is \psf\Home\Documents\Atmel Studio which seems wrong.
How can I fix this?